# Как сверстать такую прозрачную кнопку?

Tags: css3, html5, svg

Как сверстать такую кнопку? Кнопка прозрачная, сзади градиент. Если бы был простой фон, можно бы было через псевдоэлемент. Если вырезать с градиентом и спозиционировать, то при адаптиве будут не стыковки.

http://prnt.sc/ef3ik4

[image]

Comment: Эту кнопку можно посмотреть где-то онлайн и не картинкой?

Comment: Решение такое: делаем рамку и скругление, но вот только рамку с левой стороны убираем, фон прозрачный. Вырезаем закругления верх/низ и задаем их псевдоэлементами. Обарачиваем кнопку в еще один блок, и этому блоку через псевдоэлемент задаем иконку телефона

Answer (score 3):

Запоздал с ответом но только увидел

Стрелку взял здесь: https://www.flaticon.com/categories/arrows

Позиционировал и получилось вот это

```css
* {
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.parent {
  width: 220px;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ar {
  fill: orange;
  stroke: orange;
}

.frame {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

.arrow {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: -20px;
}

.btn_outer {
  fill: none;
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 4;
  mask: url(#mask);
}

.txt {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="frame">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 200" width="200" class="fr">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
        <rect x="5" y="40" width="24" height="180" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="580" height="180" x="10" y="10" ry="80" class="btn_outer"/>
    <text x="150" y="120" class="txt">Отправить</text>
  </svg>
    <div class="arrow">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="60" class="ar">
      <path transform="scale(0.8)"d="M506.206,179.012L360.025,32.834c-3.617-3.617-7.898-5.426-12.847-5.426s-9.233,1.809-12.847,5.426
        c-3.617,3.619-5.428,7.902-5.428,12.85v73.089h-63.953c-135.716,0-218.984,38.354-249.823,115.06C5.042,259.335,0,291.03,0,328.907
        c0,31.594,12.087,74.514,36.259,128.762c0.57,1.335,1.566,3.614,2.996,6.849c1.429,3.233,2.712,6.088,3.854,8.565
        c1.146,2.471,2.384,4.565,3.715,6.276c2.282,3.237,4.948,4.859,7.994,4.859c2.855,0,5.092-0.951,6.711-2.854
        c1.615-1.902,2.424-4.284,2.424-7.132c0-1.718-0.238-4.236-0.715-7.569c-0.476-3.333-0.715-5.564-0.715-6.708
        c-0.953-12.938-1.429-24.653-1.429-35.114c0-19.223,1.668-36.449,4.996-51.675c3.333-15.229,7.948-28.407,13.85-39.543
        c5.901-11.14,13.512-20.745,22.841-28.835c9.325-8.09,19.364-14.702,30.118-19.842c10.756-5.141,23.413-9.186,37.974-12.135
        c14.56-2.95,29.215-4.997,43.968-6.14s31.455-1.711,50.109-1.711h63.953v73.091c0,4.948,1.807,9.232,5.421,12.847
        c3.62,3.613,7.901,5.424,12.847,5.424c4.948,0,9.232-1.811,12.854-5.424l146.178-146.183c3.617-3.617,5.424-7.898,5.424-12.847
        C511.626,186.92,509.82,182.636,506.206,179.012z"/>
        <path d="m350,20 130,130 -120,120" fill="none" stroke-width="20" class="bullet"/>
     </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием CSS.
Иконка шрифтовая, но можно использовать и картинку.

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css');

body {
  background: blue;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::before {
  content: '\f122';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Топорно, но показывает как это можно сделать.
Вместо `background:red` у  `.your-button:before` указываете картинку и `background-size:cover` что бы она занимала весь "квадратик"

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.your-button {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-left: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.your-button:before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="your-button">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать нужную форму кнопки в фотошопе. Затем ставишь через CSS фон который сделал:

```
.button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background: url("images/button_black.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Получится что-то вроде этого:

[image: пример кнопки]

Comment: Бррррррррррр...